# How to configure Gson to serialize a set of JSR-303 ConstraintViolation objects?

Tags: json, hibernate, gson, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I can't seem to find out how to serialize Hibernate's implementation of constraint violations using Gson.

Here's what I've tried so far.

#### Approach 1

```
MyPojo aPojo = new MyPojo();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Set<ConstraintViolation<MyPojo>> violations = validator.validate(aPojo);
System.out.println(gson.toJson(violations));
```

Fails with this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: com.bar.baz.MyPojo. 
Forgot to register a type adapter?
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:67)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:107)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:593)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:572)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:527)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:507)
```

#### Approach 2

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Set<ConstraintViolation<MyPojo>> violations = validator.validate(MyPojo);

System.out.println(
    gson.toJson(violations,
                new TypeToken<ConstraintViolation<MyPojo>>() {}.getType())
);
```

Fails by not serializing MyPojo's properties:

Output: `{}`.

#### Approach 3

I was expecting this approach to delegate serialization to my custom Serializer but it still fails:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(
        new TypeToken<ConstraintViolation<MyPojo>>() {}.getType(),
        new JsonSerializer<ConstraintViolation<MyPojo>>() {
            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(ConstraintViolation<MyPojo> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                JsonObject result = new JsonObject();

                result.addProperty("aTestProperty", "A Test Value");

                return result;
            }

        });

Gson gson = builder.create();

Set<ConstraintViolation<MyPojo>> violations = validator.validate(MyPojo);
System.out.println(gson.toJson(violations));
```

However it fails with this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: 
com.bar.baz.MyPojo. 
Forgot to register a type adapter?
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:67)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:107)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:593)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:572)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:527)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:507)
```

#### Approach 4

Looking at the error message, I though this might work:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(
                new TypeToken<ConstraintViolation<MyPojo>>() {}.getType(),
                new JsonSerializer<ConstraintViolation<MyPojo>>() {
                    @Override
                    public JsonElement serialize(ConstraintViolation<MyPojo> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();

                        result.addProperty("aTestProperty", "A Test Value");

                        return result;
                    }

                });

        builder.registerTypeAdapter(
                new TypeToken<MyPojo>() {}.getType(),
                new JsonSerializer<MyPojo>() {
                    @Override
                    public JsonElement serialize(MyPojo src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();

                        result.addProperty("anotherTestProperty", "Another Test Value");

                        return result;
                    }

                });

        Gson gson = builder.create();

        Set<ConstraintViolation<MyPojo>> violations = validator.validate(MyPojo);
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(violations));
```

But it fails with a similar error.

#### Approach 5: Working but ugly

The only thing that I've managed to make work is to register the serializer with the type of the vendor (Hibernate) specific implementation for ConstraintViolation:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<MyPojo>> violations = validator.validate(MyPojo);

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(
        new TypeToken<ConstraintViolationImpl>() {}.getType(),
        new JsonSerializer<ConstraintViolation<MyPojo>>() {
            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(ConstraintViolation<MyPojo> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                JsonObject result = new JsonObject();

                result.addProperty("aTestProperty", "A Test Value");

                return result;
            }

        });

Gson gson = builder.create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(violations));
```

---

Is there a way to make this work without relying on the concrete implementation of `ConstraintViolation` (i.e. `org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintViolationImpl`)?

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be a reasonable approach to serialize `javax.validation.ConstraintViolation` objects. In fact, even Jackson errs while trying to serialize the set:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: fromIndex(0) > toIndex(-1) (through reference chain: java.util.HashSet[0]->org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintViolationImpl["propertyPath"]->org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.path.PathImpl["pathWithoutLeafNode"]->org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.path.PathImpl["pathWithoutLeafNode"]->org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.path.PathImpl["pathWithoutLeafNode"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
```

For the time being, I just convert the set of errors into a set of custom POJOs I've written and serialize that instead.

#### Custom ValidationError POJO:

```
public class ValidationError {

    private String className;
    private String propertyPath;
    private String errorMessage;

    public static Set<ValidationError> fromViolations(Set violations) {
        Set<ValidationError> errors = new HashSet<ValidationError>();

        for (Object o : violations) {
            ConstraintViolation v = (ConstraintViolation) o;

            ValidationError error = new ValidationError();
            error.setClassName(v.getRootBeanClass().getSimpleName());
            error.setErrorMessage(v.getMessage());
            error.setPropertyPath(v.getPropertyPath().toString());
            errors.add(error);
        }

        return errors;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }

    public void setClassName(String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }

    public String getPropertyPath() {
        return propertyPath;
    }

    public void setPropertyPath(String propertyPath) {
        this.propertyPath = propertyPath;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ValidationError{" +
                "className='" + className + '\'' +
                ", propertyPath='" + propertyPath + '\'' +
                ", errorMessage='" + errorMessage + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

#### Sample usage:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<MyBean>> violations = validator.validate(myBean);
Set<ValidationError> errors = ValidationError.fromViolations(violations);

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(errors));
```

### Update

For the sake of record, it is worth mentioning that XStream can serialize the set of constraint violations like a charm:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
System.out.println(xstream.toXML(violations));
```

However the generated the object graph is way too much verbose and is not suitable for use in production anyway. You can see the sample output [here](https://gist.github.com/behrangsa/9154765).